# Encrypt and decrypt a xml file

Tags: c#, xml, encryption

I am working with XML. I want to encrypt and decrypt it with password. I looked up on MSDN and try some examples:[Link 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb7w85t6.aspx),[Link 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229746.aspx),[Link 3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229744.aspx).
Of courses, it works well, but just at the time (I mean in the same project and use the same key Algorithm variable). I realize it generate a hash code each time the program running.
So when I fix that code to save all XML content to file and then I load that file to decrypt so it's not working.
What I have to do now?
I appreciate your help.

Comment: You didn't tag or mention any programming language. In what are you trying to do this?

Comment: I mostly forgot that, sorry. I'm working with c#.